# How to Make a test method Not Runnable in Visual Studio Unit Test

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, testing

How to Make a test method not runnable in Visual Studio Unit Test ?
using visual studio 2010 with .NET 4.0.

Suppose I have 10 test methods out of which, 1 test method is not working due to external dependencies. If I want to run all 10, then I will get error in one test.

One solution is: Don't run the test. But I need to know, is there any Attributes or anything like that, which simply bypasses the test and it will not be run.

I tried with `[WorkItem(1234)]` Attribute, but still the test is running.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: removing testmethod attribute?

Comment: Yes..that can be a solution, but doesn't look promising...thanks though

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, you can add the `Ignore` attribute to the test you want to skip:

```
[TestMethod, Ignore]
public void ThisTestWontRun()
{
    // Test code here
}
```